Prove that "max independent set is larger than max clique" is NP-Hard
We define B as:
$B = \{ <G> | \text{ G is an undirected graph in which} \\
\text{the number of vertices in the largest independent set} \\
\text{is greater than the number of vertices in the largest clique} \}$
Can you prove that B is NP-Hard? I have tried to polynomialy reduce from $CLIQUE$ but couldn't get it to work (I have tried to look at the complement graph, and add vertices)

To prove the NP-hardness of the problem B under the polynomial-time many-one reduction, we can reduce from the maximum independent set problem.
We are given a graph of size $n$ and an integer $k$, to determine if the graph contains an independent of size at least $k$.
The reduction algorithm construct an instance of the problem B by adding $n$ isolated vertices and an $(n+k)$-clique to the original graph. Then,

There exists an independent set of size $k$ in the the original graph if and only if there exists an independent set of size $n+k+1$ in the new graph.
The maximum clique size of the new graph is $n+k$.


I think you need to add $n+1$ isolated vertices and ask whether there is an independent set of size $n+k+1$.

Thank you, you mean the independent-set problem, right?
because asking if there's an independent set of size k is the same as asking if there's an independent set of size at least k

You are not given an integer k. You didn’t use the specific sub problems at all, and it is easy to create problems A, B where A has always / never / sometimes a larger solution than B. This problem is genuinely difficult.
